# php preg_replace question

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I was expecting this:

```
echo preg_replace('/[^a-zA-z0-9]*/', '_', ' foo Bar #1 -');
```

to output this:

```
'foo_Bar_1_'
```

But using ideone [http://www.ideone.com/Q80v3] its outputting:

```
'__f_o_o__B_a_r__1__'
```

And I can't work out why that is.. and how to achieve what I want, that it outputs 'foo_Bar_1_'

If I remove the *

```
echo preg_replace('/[^a-zA-z0-9]/', '_', ' foo Bar #1 -');
```

it outputs:

```
'_foo_Bar__1__'
```

but I don't want lazy match (only one underscore pr. replacement)

Comment: thank you for answers. doesn't the pattern [^a-zA-z0-9] mean 'anything but letters a to z (large and small) and numbers 0 to 9'? why would it then find 'something invisible' in between the letters that it replaces with (where it inserts) an underscore here?

Comment: The `*` quantifier means _"zero or more"_. Zero. Get it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
    echo preg_replace('/[^\w\d]+/', '_', trim(' foo Bar #1 -'));
?>
```

**Output:**

```
foo_Bar_1_
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems to work if you use a `+` instead of a `*`

**EDIT**
Actually, that outputs `_foo_Bar_1_` instead of `foo_Bar_1`. However, I don't know if there's a regex-only way to do that. Because you're giving it stuff at the beginning and end of the string that you're telling it to replace with underscores.

The quickest way to *actually* do what you want that comes to mind is regex and trim:

```
$str = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-z0-9]+/', '_', $str);
$str = trim($str, '_');
```

**EDIT 2 (MAYBE I'LL ACTUALLY READ YOUR QUESTION AND UNDERSTAND WHAT YOU WANT)**
Nevermind, jnpcl's answer works perfectly. And it's just one regex!